# Compute the powerset

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have some problems to know why this statement is true.

$$|\mathcal{P}(A\times B)|=64$$

With this instrutions : Let $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{b,\{c\}\}$.Mark the following statements True or False:

Comment: `\times` rather than `\chi` to give $\times$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $|A \times B|=|A| \times |B|$ and $|\wp(A)|=2^{|A|}$…

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I am sorry, I don't understand...

Comment: @Stephan.  In your question, what are $|A|$ and $|B|$? So what are $|A \times B|$ and $|\mathcal{P}(A\times B)|$?

Comment: || this sign means the cardinality. In this problem I would like to know why the cardinality of the powerset $ A \chi B$ is 64.

Comment: Ask yourself, what is the cardinality of $|A\times B|$?

Comment: for me the cardinality is 6

Comment: thank you for your explication , it is $2^6$